# How to pass the object itself which is creating in model method save()

Tags: python, django

I would like to pass the object which itself is creating in the model method save. How can I do it?

```
class Legal(ApplicationAbstractFields):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='legal')
    legal_product_cat = models.ForeignKey(TechniqueCategory, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    legal_product_cat_type = models.ForeignKey(TechniqueCategoryType, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    legal_product_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=254)
    legal_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=254)
​
​
​
   def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_sent == True:
            Notification.objects.create(
             # HERE HOW TO PASS THE OBJECT Legal itself???
                legal=self.objects,
                is_viewed=False,
                user=self.user,
                event='Your application was received')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `legal=self`? Is that what you want? Note this won't work if the `Legal` object is yet not created

Answer (score 0):

You first need to save the object to the database: if you create an object then before you save that object in the database, it has no primary key. Next you can simply work with `self`:

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #         ↓ first save the object
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.is_sent == True:
            Notification.objects.create(
                legal=self,
                is_viewed=False,
                user=self.user,
                event='Your application was received'
            )
```